# Including JSP page into another JSP page, how to avoid multiple HEAD / BODY sections?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jspinclude

I would like to include a JSP page into another JSP page. Let's say that I have `master.jsp` that is including `slave.jsp`.

As `slave.jsp` has its own `<head>` section for dealing with JavaScript and CSS, is  there a way or maybe another method to merge the `master`and `slave` **HEAD**s section into a single one? Also the same should done for the **BODY**s section.

I have been using **sitemesh** recently but I think is quite impractical to setup a template for each page.

Comment: Hi, I would recommend you tiles for simples pages or velocity for more complex ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went for this solution by passing a **parameter** when including the page.

in **master.jsp**

```
<head>
  blablabla
  <c:import url="slave.jsp">
    <c:param name="sectionName" value="HEAD" />
  </c:import>
</head>
<body>
  blablabla
  <c:import url="slave.jsp">
  </c:import>
</body>
```

and then in **slave.jsp** the parameter is read and the custom part of the page is rendered.

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${param.sectionName == 'HEAD'}">
     head section here [without the <HEAD> tags !]
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
     body section here [without the <BODY> tags !]
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

not too nice to see but working. In this way I am able to remove the duplication of `HEAD` and `BODY` parts.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot and should not merge two `<html>` documents in each other. This would produce invalid output. Better include CSS/JS conditionally with help of [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`c:if`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/if.html) or [`c:choose`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/choose.html) tags.

Basic example:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>
    <c:if test="${isAdminPage}">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="admin.js"></script>
    </c:if>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Outside of sitemesh, you're pretty much out of luck. However I would reconsider your design if you think that the setup per page is impractical. How many pages will your app have?

Comment: So I guess that the only solution is to split the slave.jsp page in two parts slave-head.jsp and slave-body. In this way I can just include one of each in the appropriate section.

Comment: Or maybe also using the <c:import... with a param to include head/body section. Guess I will go for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could also extend the conditional option, and make a `meta.jsp` (for example), which contains a `Map` for each of the head elements - meta tags, css hrefs, script hrefs, and use the name of the jsp as a key in that Map. Then you call `request.getRequestURI()`, and show whatever you have put in the map under that key. 
Not a very beautiful solution, but working.