# Multiple <head> <body> tags in the jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp, jspinclude

I have jsp page, that include multiple jsp pages. And in result i have multiple `<head> <body>` tags in the main jsp page. Everything is working, but I've read that multiple tags on one page not recomended.

So, is it any solution for merge all `<head> <body>` tags to one? And is it neccessary to merge?

I saw some related question there, but there it were solutions.

Thaks =)

Comment: If you are referring to the `<head>` and `<body>` tags as edited, you should be removing them in the respective JSPs.

Comment: I use <jsp:include ...> . On the main page i have multiple <head> <body> <html>.

Comment: see also [Including JSP page into another JSP page, how to avoid multiple HEAD / BODY sections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841274/including-jsp-page-into-another-jsp-page-how-to-avoid-multiple-head-body-sect?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the duplicate tags from included jsps.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand from where I must remove tham. Sorry for stupid question. It's inattention.

Comment: from all the jsp which you are including in main jsp using jsp:include tag.

Answer (score 2):

> Everything is working, but I've read that multiple tags on one page not recommended.

It is "not recommended" to have multiple `<head>` or `<body>` elements because it is malformed HTML.  It is only working because the web browsers you are testing against try to make sense of malformed HTML ... and in this case, they apparently succeed.

> So, is it any solution for merge all `<head>` `<body>` tags to one?

There's no magic solution:

- You could refactoring the included JSPs so that they are HTML fragments rather than self-contained pages.  (In other words, remove the  `<head>` and `<body>` tags from the included JSPs.)
- You could implement some JSTL tags that can conditionally add the `<head>` and `<body>` elements depending depending on the context.
- You could try using `<iframe>` elements rather than including the sub-pages into a "merged" page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more careful / controlled with the jsp includes so that you don't end up with bad HTML, as you are getting now. While most browsers will accept poorly formed markup, it will cause you lots of problems down the road.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the jsps that are included in other pages should not include <html>, <head> and <body> tags.

Comment: Perhaps you should remove them?

Comment: Yes, I want. But i cant because html code generated by the servlet container in runtime.

Comment: I mean remove them from the included jsps.

Comment: Thanks. I've just do it too. This tag was automatic generated by ID and I didn't notice them.